# How to assign null to or unassign a Bash variable if parameter is set?

Tags: bash, variable

Variable `USE_TLS` is to be unset, `null`, or empty when TLS is not to be used, but set to `1` when TLS must be enforced. I require it to be enforced by default (i.e., set), but not if I specify another variable `do_not_use_tls` be set to `1`.

```
# this assigns null or empty
USE_TLS=${do_not_use_tls:-""}

# this assigns empty or null
USE_TLS=${do_not_use_tls:+""}
```

Is there a substitution which will set `USE_TLS` when `do_not_use_tls` is `null` or unset, but not assign it a value otherwise? I was trying the following, but these do not work:

```
USE_TLS=${do_not_use_tls:+${do_not_use_tls:-""}}

USE_TLS=${do_not_use_tls:-${do_not_use_tls:+null}}
```

Comment: are you intentionally trying to avoid an if construct?

Comment: Also I have a hard time following the logic you've laid out.  Can you show examples of if `do_not_use_tls=1` then `USE_TLS` should be set to `foo`?

Comment: What's wrong with `[ "${do_not_use_tls:-0}" -eq 1 ] && unset USE_TLS`?

Comment: @jesse_b, yes I was trying inline, and @Chris Davies, thank you for ```unset```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for seems to be

```bash
unset -v USE_TLS
[ "${do_not_use_tls-}" = 1 ] || USE_TLS=1
```

This first unsets the `USE_TLS` variable (this is not strictly needed if you are confident that it won't have a previous value), and then sets it to `1` unless `$do_not_use_tls` is `1`.

Or even more unambiguously,

```bash
if [ "${do_not_use_tls-}" = 1 ]; then
    unset -v USE_TLS
else
    USE_TLS=1
fi
```

I use `"${do_not_use_tls-}"` rather than just `"$do_not_use_tls"` to not generate an error in case `set -u` aka `set -o nounset` is in effect.

You can't really use the examples that you show (all on the form of an assignment to `USE_TLS` with a value that is some expansion of the `do_not_use_tls` variable) because you need to test the value of `$do_not_use_tls` to see whether it's `1` or not.

Comment: or, to explicitly start with the stated default: `USE_TLS=1; [ "${do_not_use_tls-}" = 1 ] && unset USE_TLS`

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, that's certainly another possibility.